# Number of consumer not shrinking when there is not load in JMS queue

Tags: spring, apache-camel, jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I am writing a JMS consumer using `spring-jms` to consume message from the ActiveMQ Artemis broker. I am investigating the behaviour of 3 properties: `concurrentConsumers`, `maxConcurrentConsumers`, and `idleConsumerLimit`.

Expected behaviour is when load in queue increase consumer should scale up to `maxConcurrentConsumers` and when load decreases consumer should scale down to `idleConsumerLimit`.

But this is not happening with `spring-jms` and ActiveMQ Artemis. When there is no message in the queue consumer count is not coming down instead it retaining all the `maxConcurrentConsumers`.

I am using spring DMLC container

```xml
    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="destinationName" value="TestingInQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="20"/>
        <property name="idleConsumerLimit" value="5"/>
    </bean>
```

Complete context XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://localhost:61616</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">admin</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">admin</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
        <property name="jndiName" value="ConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="destinationQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="TestingInQueue" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="destinationQueue" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageListener" class="com.practise.SampleListener">
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
        <property name="queue" ref="destinationQueue" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="destinationName" value="TestingInQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="20"/>
        <property name="idleConsumerLimit" value="5"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:

- `maxConcurrentConsumers` : Your maximum consumers under load
- `concurrentConsumers` : You will eventually get here if you are idle for some time. (The time it takes to reach here depends on next 3 params)

The following 3 are to avoid consumers drastically scaling up and down between `maxConcurrentConsumers` and `concurrentConsumers` without any time delay.

- `idleConsumerLimit`
- `maxMessagesPerTask`
- `idleTaskExecutionLimit`

**Example**

If you start with heavy load, you will have 20 (`maxConcurrentConsumers`) consumers. Then if you make the queue empty, it will scale down to 5 (`idleConsumerLimit`) . Then it will wait `idleTaskExecutionLimit` attempts to be reached and then scale down to 1 (`concurrentConsumers`).
`idleTaskExecutionLimit` is number of fetch attempts which resulted in empty fetch where each fetch take `receiveTimeout` (default 1000ms) time unit.

**Issue:**

Default value of `maxMessagesPerTask` is `-1` and `idleConsumerLimit` is not taking effect if `maxMessagesPerTask` is not greater than zero

**Solution:**

When specifying `idleConsumerLimit`, specify `maxMessagesPerTask` too.

> Specify a number of 10 to 100 messages to balance between rather long-lived and rather short-lived tasks here for `maxMessagesPerTask`

**Reference**

- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1412643
- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setMaxMessagesPerTask-int-)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Setting maxMessagesPerTask value worked. After setting this value consumer count came down to concurrentConsumers count but not to idleConsumerLimit.  What is the effect of idleConsumerLimit in this configuration?

Comment: Even with ``maxMessagesPerTask``, ``idleConsumerLimit`` not taking effect, but consumer count able to shrink down to ``concurrentConsumers `` count.

Comment: I set ``maxMessagesPerTask`` as 10 for testing, then consumer count came down to 1 that is ``concurrentConsumer`` count. If i start the application with empty queue then 1 consumer created. 
I expect while scaling down consumer count has to be 5 that is ``idleConsumerLimit``

Comment: Yes It was ignored

Comment: with ```idleTaskExecutionLimit``` property after making queue empty after sometime consumer gradually shrinking to 1. my question here is how long will wait from ```idleTaskExecutionLimit ``` to ```idleConsumerLimit```(5) ? Can you help pls

Comment: how long will wait from idleTaskExecutionLimit  to idleConsumerLimit(5) ? Can you help pls - Yes. It will wait 5 times before it shrinks to math.max(idleConsumerLimit, concurrentConsumer)